# Where to set breakpoint on multi-line statement?

Tags: python, syntax, multiline, pdb

Considering the following source code:

```py
1    f(
2      foo(),
3      bar(),
4      spam(a,
5           b,
6      ),
7     )
```

Where should I set a breakpoint if I want the code to break immediately before calling `f`, but after calling `foo()`, `bar()`, and `spam(a, b)`?  If I set it at line 1 the breakpoint will occur too early.  But I tried setting it at line 7, and pdb never broke into code in the first place.  Where do I set the breakpoint and why?

Comment: You cannot set breakpoints other than line 1. But you can use step in, step out to skip functions. So if you want to debug function `bar`. You can press `step in` and `step out`, then you've skipped function `foo` and are ready to enter function `bar`.

Comment: @Sraw Are you sure?  I managed to set a breakpoint at lines 3 or 4, for example.

Comment: Hum... Maybe I remember wrongly :( But I believe this method should still be helpful? As you can set the breakpoint at line 4 and skip `spam` function to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Sraw I'd still need to know when to type `next` and when to type `step`...

Answer (score 0):

You can put break point inside the function definition of `f` then it will break at your desired location. And the reason is `f` will be called after the execution of `foo()`,`bar()` and `spam(a,b)`

Or

Write a wrapper function

```
def wrapper(fun,a,b):
    temp = fun(a,b)
    return temp

f(
      foo(),
      bar(),
      wrapper(spam,a,b),
     )
```

And put beak point at return statement

Comment: True, but that only works if I know where `f` is defined.  I might not know this; it might be dynamic.